# Constantly adding elements to Flatlist in react native causing the entire page to constantly refresh

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, performance

I am currently working on a react native page on Android, there is a requirement to allow user to type something and add this thing into a list with the latest item on top. I'm using a Flatlist to render these text and currently I'm encountering performance issue.

in my parent component:

```
const SomePage = () => {
  ...
  const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState<SomeType[]>([]);
  ...

  const addItem = (item) => {
    let newData = { id: item.id, desc: item.desc, index: someCounter };
    setMyArray([newData, ...myArray]);
  }
```

codes to render each item in the flatlist:

```
  const renderItemList = useCallback(
    ({item, index}, someFunction) => {
      const closeRow = (closeIndex: number) => {
        // close an item when another is opened
        if (
          prevOpenedRow.current &&
          prevOpenedRow.current !== row[closeIndex]
        ) {
          prevOpenedRow.current.close();
        }

        prevOpenedRow.current = row[closeIndex];
      };
      const renderRightActions = (progress, dragX, someFunction) => {
        const opacity = dragX.interpolate({
          inputRange: [-80, 0],
          outputRange: [1, 0],
          extrapolate: 'clamp',
        });
        return (
          <Animated.View style={[styles.swipedRow, {opacity}]}>
            <Animated.View style={styles.deleteButton}>
              <Pressable style={{alignItems: 'center'}} onPress={someFunction}>
                <SvgDelete />
                <Animated.Text style={styles.deleteButtonText}>
                  Delete
                </Animated.Text>
              </Pressable>
            </Animated.View>
          </Animated.View>
        );
      };

      return (
        <Swipeable
          key={item.id}
          overshootFriction={3}
          onSwipeableWillOpen={() => {
            someTextInputRef?.current?.blur();
          }}
          renderRightActions={(progress, dragX) =>
            renderRightActions(progress, dragX, onClick)
          }
          onSwipeableOpen={() => closeRow(index)}
          ref={ref => (row[index] = ref)}>
          <View>
            <View>
              <Text>#{item.index}</Text>
              <SvgDot /> // some image
              <Text>{item.id}</Text>
              <SvgDot /> // some image
              <SvgSealDot
                stroke={Colors.Black30}
              />
              <Text>ID</Text>
            </View>
            <Text>{item.desc}</Text>
          </View>
        </Swipeable>
      );
    },
    [row, myArray],
  );

  const someFunction = () => {
    ...
  }
```

code to render the FlatList:

```
  return (
    <View>
      ...
        <FlatList
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
          data={myArray}
          renderItem={item =>
            renderItemList(item, () => {
              someFunction(item);
            })
          }
          keyExtractor={item => {
            return item.id.toString();
          }}
          removeClippedSubviews
        </FlatList>
      ... 
    </View>
  );
}
```

noted the FlatList is part of this page, if anything in this page, everything in the FlatList will be rendered again even when I'm using useCallback for each item render

This is the very confusing part as when I add a new item to the array, firstly the page re-render again because some prop changed

[image]

then the FlatList re-render again because there are some new elements (everything will get re-rendered which take a astonishing 600ms - 1000ms to re-render every single elements in the list. There might be up to 200 items in the list

Is there anything I can do to prevent these things from re-rendering? I need to add 200 items one by one and each insertion into the list will cause the page to re-render once (including everything in the FlatList), then the FlatList to re-render everything again.

I've tryed removeClippedSubviews but it doesn't have any effect for this issue.

I've also tried to use a myArray.map(...some useCallback functions to render) but everything is still re-rendering

Just looking for ways to stop everything from re-rendering so the application can add everything smoothly into this list

Answer (score 1):

Try with BigList, This is a high-performance list view for React Native with support for complex layouts using a similar FlatList usage to make easy the replacement.

**Example**

if you have any state which you want to use inside render and you want to avoid unnecessary thing of re-rendering in this case use use callback

```
const renderItem = useCallback(({ item, index }: { item: any, index: number }) => {
  return (
    <View style={s.content}>
      
    </View>
  )
}, []); // add state dependency here


<BigList
    data={event}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    itemHeight={70}
  />
```

Comment: one thing I'm not sure is why does the useCallback items still re-render, does big list solve this issue? I think I'll try it out!

Comment: It depends on you if you have any state which you want to use inside render and you want to avoid unnecessary thing of re-rendering in this case use use callback

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: sorry big list didn't solve the issue, I later found out it's because I'm using a state to hold the array, when I want to add something new due to the immutable nature of state I have to make a new copy of that array, resulting in everything get refreshed immediately.

Comment: As a solution I use mutable references for the data array, so when I add things to the array I can just do append so useCalback will work because it is still the same item